# "Unable to get value of the property 'appendChild': object is null or undefined" while opening page in new window

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I get the following javascript exception while I opening web page in new window

> Unable to get value of the property 'appendChild': object is null or undefined.

I use window.open function to open my page in new window, although this exception appear only in IE browser.

the following is my web page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
MasterPageFile="~/Page.Master" 
CodeBehind="DocumentForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="Docunet.WebViewer.DocumentForm" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Atalasoft.dotImage.WebControls" Namespace="Atalasoft.Imaging.WebControls"
    TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="head" ContentPlaceHolderID="headContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">

    <link href='<%# "Styles/DocumentFormStyles" + this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Layout", "Culture").ToString() + ".css"  %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="content" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">

    <div id="mainTitleBox" class="MainTitleBox">
        <asp:Label ID="mainTitleLabel" runat="server" 
            class="MainTitle"  
            meta:resourceKey="mainTitleLabel" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="viewBox" class="ViewBox">
                <div class="instanceDataBox">
                    <asp:TabContainer ID="tabContainer" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" >
                        <asp:TabPanel ID="generalTabPanel" runat="server"  
                            CssClass="Text"
                            meta:resourceKey="generalTabPanel" HeaderText="" >
                            <ContentTemplate> 
                                <div class="Text">
                                    <p class='<%# this.ReadRecordMode ? "DataParagraph" : "EditModeDataParagraph" %>'>
                                        <asp:Label ID="numberTitleLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="titleControl" 
                                            meta:resourceKey="numberTitleLabel" Text="<%# this.NumberFieldName %>" ></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="numberLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="valueControl" 
                                            Visible="<%# this.ReadRecordMode %>"></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class='<%# this.ReadRecordMode ? "DataParagraph" : "EditModeDataParagraph" %>'>
                                        <asp:Label ID="yearTitleLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="titleControl" 
                                            meta:resourceKey="yearTitleLabel" Text="<%# this.YearFieldName %>" ></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="yearLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="valueControl" 
                                            Visible="<%# this.ReadRecordMode %>"></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class='<%# this.ReadRecordMode ? "DataParagraph" : "EditModeDataParagraph" %>'>
                                        <asp:Label ID="codeTitleLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="titleControl" 
                                            meta:resourceKey="codeTitleLabel" Text="<%# this.CodeFieldName %>" ></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="codeLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="valueControl" 
                                            Visible="<%# this.ReadRecordMode %>"></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class='<%# this.ReadRecordMode ? "DataParagraph" : "EditModeDataParagraph" %>'>
                                        <asp:Label ID="categoryTitleLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="titleControl" 
                                            meta:resourceKey="categoryTitleLabel" Text="<%# this.CategoryFieldName %>" ></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="categoryLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="valueControl" 
                                            Visible="<%# this.ReadRecordMode %>"></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class='<%# this.ReadRecordMode ? "DataParagraph" : "EditModeDataParagraph" %>'>
                                        <asp:Label ID="dateTitleLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="titleControl" 
                                            meta:resourceKey="dateTitleLabel" Text="<%# this.DateFieldName %>" ></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="dateLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="valueControl" 
                                            Visible="<%# this.ReadRecordMode %>"></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class='<%# this.ReadRecordMode ? "DataParagraph" : "EditModeDataParagraph" %>'>
                                        <asp:Label ID="archiveDocumentTitleLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="titleControl" 
                                            meta:resourceKey="archiveDocumentTitleLabel" Text="<%# this.ArchiveDocumentFieldName %>" ></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="archiveDocumentLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="valueControl" 
                                            Visible="<%# this.ReadRecordMode %>"></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class='<%# this.ReadRecordMode ? "DataParagraph" : "EditModeDataParagraph" %>' style="height:70px;" >
                                        <asp:Label ID="subjectTitleLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="titleControl"
                                            meta:resourceKey="subjectTitleLabel" Text="<%# this.SubjectFieldName %>" ></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="subjectLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="valueControl" 
                                            Visible="<%# this.ReadRecordMode %>"></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class='<%# this.ReadRecordMode ? "DataParagraph" : "EditModeDataParagraph" %>' style="height:70px;" >
                                        <asp:Label ID="notesTitleLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="titleControl" 
                                            meta:resourceKey="notesTitleLabel" Text="<%# this.NotesFieldName %>" ></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="notesLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="valueControl" 
                                            Visible="<%# this.ReadRecordMode %>"></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class='<%# this.ReadRecordMode ? "DataParagraph" : "EditModeDataParagraph" %>'>
                                        <asp:Label ID="mainDocumentNumberTitleLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="titleControl" 
                                            meta:resourceKey="mainDocumentNumberTitleLabel" Text="<%# this.MainDocumentNumberFieldName %>" ></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="mainDocumentNumberLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="valueControl" 
                                            Visible="<%# this.ReadRecordMode %>"></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class='<%# this.ReadRecordMode ? "DataParagraph" : "EditModeDataParagraph" %>'>
                                        <asp:Label ID="mainDocumentDateTitleLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="titleControl" 
                                            meta:resourceKey="mainDocumentDateTitleLabel" Text="<%# this.MainDocumentDateFieldName %>" ></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="mainDocumentDateLabel" runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="valueControl" 
                                            Visible="<%# this.ReadRecordMode %>"></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:TabPanel>
                        <asp:TabPanel ID="relatedDocumentsTabPanel" runat="server"  
                            CssClass="Text"
                            meta:resourceKey="relatedDocumentsTabPanel" HeaderText="" >
                            <ContentTemplate> 
                                <div class="Text">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="relatedDocumentsGridView" runat="server" 
                                        BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="Horizontal"
                                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                                        DataKeyNames="ID"
                                        onrowdatabound="relatedDocumentsGridView_RowDataBound" 
                                        onselectedindexchanged="gridView_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" Visible="false" />
                                            <asp:TemplateField meta:resourceKey="relatedDocumentsGridViewColorField" HeaderText="" >
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle RelatedDocumentColorGridViewHeader" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle RelatedDocumentColorGridViewItem" />
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SerialNumber" meta:resourceKey="relatedDocumentsGridViewSerialNumberField" HeaderText="" >
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle RelatedDocumentSerialNumberGridViewHeader" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle RelatedDocumentSerialNumberGridViewItem" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" meta:resourceKey="relatedDocumentsGridViewCodeField" HeaderText="" >
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle RelatedDocumentCodeGridViewHeader" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle RelatedDocumentCodeGridViewItem" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" meta:resourceKey="relatedDocumentsGridViewSubjectField" HeaderText="" >
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle RelatedDocumentSubjectGridViewHeader" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle RelatedDocumentSubjectGridViewItem" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateAsString" meta:resourceKey="relatedDocumentsGridViewCreationDateField" HeaderText="" >
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle RelatedDocumentCreationDateGridViewHeader" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle RelatedDocumentCreationDateGridViewItem" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                        </Columns>
                                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                            <div>
                                                <a> <%# this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Messages", "EmptyList") %> </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                        <PagerSettings Visible="False" />
                                        <RowStyle CssClass="gridViewRow" />
                                        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selectedGridViewRow" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:TabPanel>
                        <asp:TabPanel ID="attachmentsTabPanel" runat="server"  
                            CssClass="Text"
                            meta:resourceKey="attachmentsTabPanel" HeaderText="" >
                            <ContentTemplate> 
                                <div class="Text">
                                    <asp:DataList ID="documentAttachmentsDataList" runat="server" Height="78px" 
                                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="62px" RepeatColumns="5">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div align="center">
                                                <asp:Image ID="imgAttach"  ImageUrl='<%# isAvail(Eval("ATTTYPE", "~/Images/{0}.jpg"))%>'  Width="100px" Height="100px" runat="server" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div align="center">
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbAttach" runat="server" Text="<%# Bind('NAME') %>" onclick="lbAttach_Click" Font-Size="16"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblID" style='display:none'  runat="server" Text="<%# Bind('ID') %>"></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:DataList>                                    
                                    <asp:GridView ID="attachmentsGridView" runat="server" 
                                        BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="Horizontal"
                                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                                        DataKeyNames="ID"
                                        onrowdatabound="gridView_RowDataBound" 
                                        onselectedindexchanged="gridView_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" Visible="false" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" meta:resourceKey="attachmentsGridViewNameField" HeaderText="" >
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle AttachmentNameGridViewHeader" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle AttachmentNameGridViewItem" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CREATEDATE" meta:resourceKey="attachmentsGridViewCreationDateField" HeaderText="" >
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle AttachmentCreationDateGridViewHeader" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle AttachmentCreationDateGridViewItem" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="FILENAME" meta:resourceKey="attachmentsGridViewFileField" HeaderText="" >
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle AttachmentFileGridViewHeader" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle AttachmentFileGridViewItem" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ATTTYPE" meta:resourceKey="attachmentsGridViewFileTypeField" HeaderText="" >
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle AttachmentFileTypeGridViewHeader" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle AttachmentFileTypeGridViewItem" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                        </Columns>
                                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                            <div>
                                                <a> <%# this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Messages", "EmptyList") %> </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                        <PagerSettings Visible="False" />
                                        <RowStyle CssClass="gridViewRow" />
                                        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selectedGridViewRow" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:TabPanel>
                        <asp:TabPanel ID="imagesTabPanel" runat="server"  
                            CssClass="Text"
                            meta:resourceKey="imagesTabPanel" HeaderText="" >
                            <ContentTemplate> 
                                <table style="border:1px solid black; width:100%;" >
                                    <tr> 
                                        <td style="vertical-align:top; border-right:1px solid black; width:295px;">
                                            <cc1:WebThumbnailViewer ID="documentImageWebThumbnailViewer" runat="server"
                                                Height="500px"
                                                ViewerID="documentImagesWebImageViewer"
                                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="documentImageWebThumbnailViewer_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                                            <cc1:WebImageViewer ID="documentImagesWebImageViewer" runat="server"
                                                Height="500px" Width="100%" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:TabPanel>
                        <asp:TabPanel ID="copiesTabPanel" runat="server"  
                            CssClass="Text"
                            meta:resourceKey="copiesTabPanel" HeaderText="" >
                            <ContentTemplate> 
                                <div class="Text">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="copiesGridView" runat="server" 
                                        BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="Horizontal"
                                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                                        DataKeyNames="ID"
                                        onrowdatabound="gridView_RowDataBound" 
                                        onselectedindexchanged="gridView_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" Visible="false" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SerialNumber" meta:resourceKey="copiesGridViewSerialNumberField" HeaderText="" >
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle CopiesSerialNumberGridViewHeader" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle CopiesSerialNumberGridViewItem" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TargetType" meta:resourceKey="copiesGridViewTargetTypeField" HeaderText="" >
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle CopiesTargetTypeGridViewHeader" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle CopiesTargetTypeGridViewItem" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Target" meta:resourceKey="copiesGridViewTargetNameField" HeaderText="" >
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle CopiesTargetNameGridViewHeader" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle CopiesTargetNameGridViewItem" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                        </Columns>
                                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                            <div>
                                                <a> <%# this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Messages", "EmptyList") %> </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                        <PagerSettings Visible="False" />
                                        <RowStyle CssClass="gridViewRow" />
                                        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selectedGridViewRow" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:TabPanel>
                        <asp:TabPanel ID="additionalFieldsTabPanel" runat="server"  
                            CssClass="Text"
                            meta:resourceKey="additionalFieldsTabPanel" HeaderText="" >
                            <ContentTemplate> 
                                <div class="Text">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="additionalFieldsGridView" runat="server" 
                                        BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="Horizontal"
                                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                                        DataKeyNames="ID"
                                        onrowdatabound="gridView_RowDataBound" 
                                        onselectedindexchanged="gridView_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" Visible="false" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" meta:resourceKey="additionalFieldsGridViewNameField" HeaderText="" >
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle AdditionalFieldNameGridViewHeader" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle AdditionalFieldNameGridViewItem" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>

                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" meta:resourceKey="additionalFieldsGridViewValueField" HeaderText="" >
                                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeaderStyle AdditionalFieldValueGridViewHeader" />
                                            <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewItemStyle AdditionalFieldValueGridViewItem" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                        <div>
                                            <a> <%# this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Messages", "EmptyList") %> </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <PagerSettings Visible="False" />
                                    <RowStyle CssClass="gridViewRow" />
                                    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selectedGridViewRow" />
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>                        
                </asp:TabContainer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Don't you want to **limit** your markup posting only **really meaningful** part of it?

Answer (score 0):

The page you are loading must contain some javascript function where you are trying to append a child to an object that is not initialized.

Other browsers will ignore the error and keep loading while IE breaks on it.
Debug your OnLoad code in the javascript and find where this happens.

Just add following check:

```
    if(myObj != undefined){
        myObj.AppendChild(child)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, but actually the page not contain any javascript functions,the exception fire at this point : document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)

Comment: try also setting the id of your element and use jquery $("#head")
Should be something like that, can't see your entire html file

Comment: this call "document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)" not my code.